# What is the difference between id and key fields in /{db}/_all_docs response?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

[`/{db}/_all_docs`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-all-docs) response seems to have identical `id` and `key` value. What is the difference between the two? The `key` field is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance `id` and `key` may seem redundant, however it makes sense when considering `_all_docs`.  From the documentation:

> Executes the built-in _all_docs **view**<sup>*</sup>, returning all of the documents
> in the database. With the exception of the URL parameters (described
> below), this endpoint works identically to any other view. Refer to
> the view endpoint documentation for a complete description of the
> available query parameters and the format of the returned data.

<sup>* emphasis mine</sup>

So `_all_docs` is a built-in *view*.  Consider the [view documentation](http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/docs/ddocs/ddocs.html#view-functions).  It is helpful to think of views as being composed of three fields

- id
- key
- value

User designed views generally take shape as id = document._id with
key and value produced by the `emit()` function (via the `map` function).

For example, the following map function

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.someField, doc.someValue);
}
```

generates the view id = doc._id, key = doc.someField, value = doc.someValue.